# How to get a reference to current DropTarget, upon drop failure with YUI 2.8.1 DragDrop?

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop, yui, target

I'm using the `DragDrop` component - its basically the 'grouped drop objects' example - but I cannot for the life of me obtain a reference to the `DropTarget` object at the time I dropped my drag object... when the `DropTarget` is "incorrect".

I tried intercepting `onInvalidDrop`, can't seem to catch references to a `DropTarget` there, 'this' default scopes to the Dragged object.

I tried putting a conditional within `onDragDrop` for whether a drop result was a legal target, hoping to see some result... nothing.

I then tried to do the same with `onDragEnd` as with `onDragDrop`, no cigar.

I simply want to deactivate the `DropTarget` the user failed on. I have the styles ready, I have isTarget ready to be applied... but nothing to apply it to?

URL: http://codefinger.co.nz/_testing/yui_dragdrop/dragdrop_test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware! Dav Glass of the YUI team advised that the reference I'm after is not available in Y2.8.1 DragDrop - though it is in YUI3.

Though its not feasible in my case to switch to YUI3, a suitable (if hacky) solution was to add all droppables to a single group (instead of many groups) so that they all trigger `onDragDrop`. From there, its possible to qualify in/valid drop targets based on things like the drop targets' `id`, `classNames`, or in my case some custom object props.

Problem... solved.